# Word Online Office JS - Content controls inside text boxes

Tags: javascript, office-js

We have scenarios where Text Boxes are used to position Content Controls outside of the normal text flow, both in document header/footer and in the body.

But we are unable to perform actions on these Content Controls when running on Word Online because Content Controls within Text Boxes are not part of the returned `items` array when I run the following:

```
await Word.run(async (context) => {
    let contentControls = context.document.contentControls;

    contentControls.load();

    await context.sync();

    for (let i = 0; i < contentControls.items.length; i++) {
        let cc = contentControls.items[i];
        // cc will never be the Content Control within the Text Box <- Problem!!
    }

    await context.sync();
});
```

This works fine on Word 2016 on Windows.

Is there another way to load and manipulate **all** Content Controls that works across all Word hosts?

Answer (score 0):

This is by design since TextBox is not supported on Word online, also all the contents inside it. As you can see, TextBox is rendered something as a picture on online, we can't resolve and manipulate the contents inside it.

Comment: The lack of this support makes Word Online unusable in some of our scenarios. Users of our add-in will not understand why our add-in does not work the same on Word Online as it does in Word 2016. Do you know when TextBoxes (or rather, Content Controls in TextBoxes) will be supported on Word Online?

Comment: TextBoxes in Online it's in the backlog but with no time commitment as of now.

Comment: @JuanBalmori Is there any news on this issue?